# Meaning of "ein Bein zuviel haben"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of german expression "ein Bein zuviel haben"?
As in "Vielleicht hat Herr Sommer einfach ein Bein zuviel und muß deshalb immer laufen" (c) Süskind, 
or "Der König, der ein Bein zuviel hatte" (children books name)

Comment: This isn't a common picture, it seems to be invented for this book. There is the word *Dreibeiner* for *man*, which was introduced by comedian Gaby Köster twenty years ago, but this isn't suited for a children's book.

Comment: Yes, it seems, but on the cover of a children's book (Der König, der ein Bein zuviel hatte) is clearly visible a man with two legs

Comment: Does it have penis jokes? I doubt so.

Comment: @EugenPolonski Depends on the edition. [Here](http://www.petit4.de/fotos/cd_bisch/706) is one that shows him with 3 feet :) Other editions are collections of several stories, hence the cover might not depict this particular story

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close this question: OP has provided valid examples from German literature, and the best dictionary doesn't help if what you're looking for is not listed.

Comment: Sidenote: the OP might be interested in the popular surgery pun: "*Besser arm dran als Bein ab.*"

Comment: @Janka: "Drittes Bein" als Metapher für den Penis habe ich schon Anfang der 80er gehört..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Janka](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23885/janka) commented, this is not a fixed phrase in German.

The children book is a collection of stories from [Sergio Tofano](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Tofano) (Italian title: *I cavoli a merenda*). One of the stories seems to be a about a king who literally has three legs - I found a description on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/K%C3%B6nig-ein-Bein-zuviel-hatte/dp/3446165991) that says

> Wer drei Beine hat statt nur zwei, sollte sich nicht grämen, kann er doch, falls notwendig, gleich zwei Leuten in den Allerwertesten treten.

(If you have three legs instead of just two, you shouldn't worry, because if necessary, you can kick two people in the buttocks at the same time.)

In your other example, "Die Geschichte von Herrn Sommer" by Patrick Süskind, a family is talking about a man (Herr Sommer) who refused to get into their car during severe weather. During the discussion why Herr Sommer refused, one compares him with a certain character from the Brother Grimm fairy tale *"[Sechse kommen durch die ganze Welt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Six_Made_Their_Way_in_the_World)"*. This character is a runner who cannot stop running unless he removes one of his legs. This idea was picked up - hence, the speculation arose, whether Herr Sommer (figuratively) had an extra leg, which implies that maybe he *just had to walk*.